# Is there a short way to calculate x * 2 + 1?

Tags: java

I want to calculate `x = x * 2 + 1;`

In most programming languages,
`x = x*2;` could be written like `x *= 2;`

Is there a way to save a little more spaces?

Comment: Why you want to do it, Simplicity is difficult to achieve and once achieved, it should not be made complex. There is a difference between simple code and bad code. In multi threaded systems, i++, j--, are not atomic and may lead to issues. Small space does not mean smart and also does not mean better. Expressions like i++ or i += 2  are easy to understood and easy to write in places like for loop. But do not try to go for unusual ways to write code which is not Understandable. Code should always be : T.U.B.E : Testable, Understandable, Brow-sable and Explainable. *Also see KISS principle.

Comment: The OP never said that he wanted to use this in a production system. Curiosity is a good quality in a software engineer. And it's a fun question. People who downvoted should question whether they enjoy themselves enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `x += x + 1`?

It's identical (in result) to `x = x * 2 + 1`, but with fewer characters.

And you can also use `x += -~x`, but a little more difficult to understand at first.

EDIT:

I also tried `x += ++x` and it's as same as `x = x * 2 + 1`, too. But I can't stop feeling evil with this statement because it assign a variable twice in one statement.

Answer (score 2):

How about `x *= 2; x++;` ? That's shorter than `x = x * 2 + 1;` with an identical result.

Comment: Actually it has 9 characters, and OP's statement has 8 characters.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible way too

```
x*=(2+1/x)
```

Comment: Interesting alternative, but it seems pretty dangerous in matters of floating value results. Ex. _59.00000000000001_

Comment: I think that can be taken care of by using floats values in the equation above.